# Visual Studio 2015 (ASP.NET 5): show 'Manage Bower Packages...' context menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In Visual Studio 2015, when I create a brand new solution with a brand new ASP.NET 5 project, I see the `Manage Bower Packages...` context menu when I right-click on the project:

[image]

However, when I add an ASP.NET 5 project to an existing solution, the `Manage Bower Packages...` context menu is nowhere to be seen:

[image]

Any idea how to get the `Manage Bower Packages...` context menu option to appear?

Comment: Did you add a bower configuration file for the project (right-click project => Add new item => Bower configuration file)? If that's missing you don't see the corresponding context-menu item.

Comment: @SamuliHaverinen: That was exactly it.  Once I added the `bower.json` file, I actually had to close and open Visual Studio again which tripped me a up a bit.  But in the end, adding `bower.json` solved the problem.

Comment: @SamuliHaverinen: do you want to post your answer in the answer box?  I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Thank you Johnny! Glad you got it working :)

Comment: right-click project => Add new item => Bower configuration file. This option is not coming in my VS 2015 Express.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding a Bower configuration file to the project solves this problem. This can be done by right-clicking the project, selecting `"Add new item"` from the menu and then `"Bower configuration file"` from the item templates. Visual Studio restart may be required to get the menu item to show up.

Comment: right-click project => Add new item => Bower configuration file. This option is not coming in my VS 2015 Express.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community version 15.7.0. I'm working on a .NET Core 2 project. I don't see the `Bower Configuration file` item at all in the `Add New Item` wizard suggested by @Samuli in his answer. Look at the the screenshot below:

[image]

**Solution 1** - I went into the root directory of the project from windows explorer and created an empty `bower.json` file myself. After doing this, I came back to Visual Studio and right clicked the project file in solution explorer and I was all set. `Manage Bower Packages...` option was available now in the context menu.

**Solution 2** - If you want a non-empty bower configuration file with default configuration then follow these steps :

1. Open the command/shell prompt or power shell prompt
2. Change the current working directory in the shell prompt to project's root directory
3. Run the command `bower init` on shell prompt
4. You would get `bower.json` created by answering few general answers on the shell prompt.

Comment: I followed solution1 to do this. When I opened Manage Bower packages and tried to install Angularjs, it is giving me an error saying, Failed to read bower.json . Unexpected end of json. The bower.json file is empty as of now. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I additionally needed to:

**Open the bower.json file in Visual Studio**

And then the `Manage Bower Packages...` option appeared in the right-click menu.