# Visual Studio doesn't show 'Manage Bower Packages...' context menu

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, bower

Firstly let me say I have read [This similar SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936726/visual-studio-2015-asp-net-5-show-manage-bower-packages-context-menu)

My issue is that even after adding a bower.json file (in Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET 4 MVC) , I do not see a context menu to "Manage Bower Packages...". I've tried to recreate the project, create a simpler project and create projects with different versions. I don't know what the problem could be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a co-worker provide an answer, as he was having the same problem:

1. In Visual Studio, open Tools / Extensions and Updates ….
2. Select Updates / Visual Studio Gallery and run Update 3.
3. Reboot, all that good stuff
4. Then, download this:  https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935
5. Run it from a Command prompt, though, not by double clicking the download, use the following parameters when running it.  It wouldn’t install for me anyways unless I ran it like this from a command prompt
   •   DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1
6. “Manage Bower Packages” then showed up for me in Visual Studio.

Hope this helps anyone else who's out there googling it!!