# How to use bower packages in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, bower

Face two difficulties with bower package manager in vs2017

1. In Visual Studio 2017, can not find any `.bowerrc` file under `bower.json`, so how to set the directory property? After Installation via **Manage Bower Packages UI**, packages store files in `bower_components` folder
2. How to use those packages, as in previous versions like VS 2013 write syntax in `BundleConfig.cs` to manage client packages like below. Now in VS 2017, how to use those packages in a C# Core 2 ASP.NET MVC project?

`BundleConfig.cs`:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                    "~/bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js",
                    "~/bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js",
                    "~/bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js")); 
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Related post - [How to use Bower (installed from nuget) in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26521889/465053)

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue.

In the same folder as your `bower.json` file create the file called `.bowerrc`. Inside it paste:

```
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`Right click your project solution` -> `Add New Item` -> `select Web on the left` -> `select Bower Configuration File on the list` -> `Add`

Now you can install new bower package by right click your solution -> manage bower package.

More details below:

[image]

Comment: Previous versions of .NET core web application template include bower.json by default when creating new projects but .NET Core 2 seems to have removed this file and it must be created manually as this answer suggests to make bower work correctly.

Comment: Cannot find this in latest Visual Studio 2017 (15.6.4)!

Comment: @Marcel you might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50549865/465053) answer. I faced the very same issue as you. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to the suggestions of manually creating the bower.json file which will start out empty:

- In Visual Studio right-click the Web Application project and choose `Open Command line` > `Default (CMD)`, `Developer Command Prompt` or `PowerShell`.
- If you don't have bower installed run the command `npm install -g bower` in the command prompt (requires npm).
- Run the command `bower init` and follow the instructions which will create the `bower.json` file.

If you answer yes to `set currently installed components as dependencies ?` and you already have packages installed in the `bower_components` folder it will automatically add them as dependencies in the `bower.json` file.

Comment: Not sure why I don't see the `Open Command line` option in the context menu. Then I opened `Command window` from `View menu` > `Other windows`. Still, `node --version` or `npm --version` commands were not getting detected at all. I'm using Visual Studio 2017. Rest other instructions worked for me. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26521928/465053) post to go past step 1.

Comment: Bower has been deprecated and it is recommended to use other package managers.