# How to use yarn in ASP.Net core MVC to install bootstrap in wwwroot folder

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-4, yarnpkg

recently I started learning ASP.Net core MVC.  I always used bower to install packages for my projects in Visual Studio 2017. but now I want to use yarn. since it seems bower is deprecated. but I don't know how to use yarn to install bootstarp in wwwroot folder. for bower i used bower.json and it would install bootstarp automatically. I use "yarn add bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 --dev" but it install it in node_modules in the project folder and I can't see it in the solution explorer,
thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's best to use npm(a package manager) for Asp.net core application,start by  searching and adding a package called npm by right clicking on your project name in solution explorer in vs2017 and clicking on "add" => add new item",inside the package,add in your bootstrap as a dependency as showed below,

```html
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "nameofyourapplicationinsmallcaps",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.1.0"
  }
}
```

**Next** ==> Create a root folder within your project named middleware,you would be building a custom extension/midleware(these would look into the node module folder to serve up files) in your request pipelines inside of **startup.cs** ,ensure you place the new extension which can be named app.UseNodeModules() underneath the app.UseStaticFiles() middleware( these serves up files from the wwwroot folder) as showed below,

app.UseStaticFiles(); 
app.UseNodeModules(env.ContentRootPath);

Inside the middleware folder,add a class which can be named ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs , you would be creating a app.UseStaticFiles() with its own request path pointing to the npm package,add the below to the class(you wont be using the default app.UseStaticFiles()),

```html
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using System.IO;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
{
    public  static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseNodeModules(this IApplicationBuilder app , string root)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(root, "node_modules");
            var fileprovider = new PhysicalFileProvider(path);
            var options = new StaticFileOptions();
            options.RequestPath = "/node_modules";
            options.FileProvider = fileprovider;
            app.UseStaticFiles(options);
            return app;
        }
    }
}
```

**Next** ==> look for an icon inside of your solution explorer in vs2017 named "show all files" and click it,you would see a node_module folder,expand this folder to view bootstrap=>dist=>css, drag the bootstrap.css in between the opening and closing head tag in your _Layout.cshtml.

After doing all these, you can start making use of bootstrap classes to add styling to your project.

Comment: Thanks @Eniola.A for the full description. I did it and it worked!. but in this way I can't use IntelliSense for bootstrap. how about yarn then? because I saw a lot of topics about migrations from npm to yarn

Comment: @AminLotf,sorry man,i really don't use yarn but am glad npm worked for you.
Vs2017 is smart enough to start remembering the various classes previously used and that is how i worked around it though am searching for ways to add intellisense for bootstrap in vs2017,i could use it in vs2015.

Comment: Anyway, your answer saved me a lot of headache :) also  that extension was interesting.I learnt something new

Comment: @AminLotf, I think the simplest solution till VS2017 15.8.x (with Microsoft Library Manager) release is just to copy complete lib distirb folders from ASP.NET Core MVC template (wwwroot/lib). This will made Intellisense works.