# Can't find Bower configuration file

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

The procedure is supposed to be this way:

Right click on the project -> New element -> Select Bower configuration file

The problem is after picking New element I can't find Bower configuration file.

Even when I type "bower" in the search list i get nothing.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use bower packages in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770536/how-to-use-bower-packages-in-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Right click your project solution -> Add New Item -> select Web on the
>   left -> select Bower Configuration File on the list -> Add
>
> Now you can install new bower package by right click your solution ->
>   manage bower package.

[More Information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47554918/4192897)

**If above is not working :**

Just add `bower.json` file to root of your project, you will see the `Manage bower packages ...` in the right click context of your **web project**. (even an empty file will work)

Comment: Right click your project solution -> Add New Item -> select Web on the left -> There is No Bower Configuration File on the list

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Glad it helped. mark the answer as correct answer if you feel it will also help others. @Salehl Arsenal

Answer (score 1):

Open Visual Studio 2019 ---> Search ---> bower configuration file

Answer (score 0):

In my case the file never appeared on the template list so I had to add a simple Text File and named it "bower.json" then add this code:

```
{ 
 "name": "asp.net",
  "private":  true,
  "dependencies": {
    "boostrap": "4.4.1" //This is for my project
  }
}
```

Then add another TextFile and named it ".bowerrc" and add the directory for the packages:

```
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

When I saved the files the Dependencies folder recognized it.